# time comparison not working. What could be wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, background, notifications

I worked on this code to perform a pause for my notifications through sleep time, however there is something missing that I can't quite figure it out. what could it be?

My `.m` code:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
dateFormatter.timeStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
NSString *dateTimeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:_startTime.date];
NSLog(@"Start time is %@",dateTimeString);


NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter2.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
dateFormatter2.timeStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter2.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
NSString *dateTimeString2=[dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:_endTime.date];
NSLog(@"End time is %@",dateTimeString2);



if ([[NSDate date] isEqualToDate:_startTime.date]) {
    NSLog(@"currentDate is equal to startTime");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    NSLog(@"Sleep time silent started and notification cancelled");

}

if ([[NSDate date] isEqualToDate:_endTime.date]) {
    NSLog(@"currentDate is equal to endTime");

    [self pickerSelectedRow];

    NSLog(@"Time to wake up and notification rescheduled");
}


}
```

when I click on `save` button I receive this out output which means it's working fine, however, when the time comes i don't get any output saying the notification has been cancelled or rescheduled, which means it's not working!!!

Output:

```
2013-05-03 03:04:57.481 xxx[10846:c07] Start time is 5/3/13, 3:06 AM
2013-05-03 03:04:57.482 xxx[10846:c07] End time is 5/3/13, 3:07 AM
```

what am I missing?

also, would this work in the background?

Comment: Why do you expect this code to work? You are trying to compare the start time to "now" and the end time to a different "now". It's extremely unlikely that the start time and end time will ever be equal to the corresponding "now". An `NSDate` object is down to the microsecond.

Comment: If you have an anaswer please show me! How do I compare it to the same "now"?

Comment: I don't have a full answer because it is unclear what you are trying to do. How are `_startTime.date` and `_endTime.date` set? In your two `if` statements, what do you really want to compare? Just the date portion of the `NSDate` or the date and time? To what resolution? And don't call `[NSDate date]` twice. Call it once and save it in a variable. Then compare the start and end dates against the one value.

Comment: @rmaddy what I'm trying to do is compare the current time with entered time through my 2 `DatePickers` and then disable the local notification on the first entered time and reactivate the local notification on the second entered time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different compare.  Perhaps something like this:
(All of the following should be in your .m file)

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString *dateTimeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:_startTime];
    NSLog(@"Start time is %@",dateTimeString);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter2.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter2.timeStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter2.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString *dateTimeString2=[dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:_endTime];
    NSLog(@"End time is %@",dateTimeString2);

    if ([self date:[NSDate date] compareMe:_startTime]) {
        NSLog(@"currentDate is equal to startTime");

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

        NSLog(@"Sleep time silent started and notification cancelled");

    }

    if ([self date:[NSDate date] compareMe:_endTime]) {
        NSLog(@"currentDate is equal to endTime");

        [self pickerSelectedRow];

        NSLog(@"Time to wake up and notification rescheduled");
    }
}

-(BOOL)date:(NSDate *)date1 compareMe:(NSDate *)date2 {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *date1Componenets = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];
    NSDateComponents *date2Componenets = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date2];

    return [date1Componenets year] == [date2Componenets year];
}
```

If you are going to compare dates a lot, you could put the comparing function in a different file, such as an NSDate category, but that is more complicated than I think you need.

Comment: Thank you. but it fails when I copied this code and it says `Use of undeclared identifier "date"`. I tried to declared in the `.h` but still the same. would you please show me your `.h`. Also, where should I call `if`? under the the button method? or should I take it under the `background` method in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: I set it up so that the comparing method -(boolean)date:(NSDate *date1) isEqualToDate:(NSDate *date2) would be in the same .m file.  See my edit.

Comment: @HaIR Thank you for the great work you have put. I have up-voted your answer. However, I still need to declare the Boolean into my `.h` so I can test it. If you can show me your `.h` or tell me how to declare it. even if you have a link to a tutorial would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am so embarassed.  Its just an equate for BOOL!  Bad on me.  I edited my answer to normal syntax.

Comment: @HalR You can't use the `==` operator to see if the two `NSDateComponents` objects are equal. You must use  the `isEqual:` method. And to be honest, I'm not sure that even works with `NSDateComponents`. You might have to compare each of the three desired values.

Comment: @rmaddy so what is your suggested answer?

Comment: @user1949873 See my latest comment below your question.

Comment: @HalR still not working! Perhaps you can test it uot and tell what could be wrong?

Comment: I edited my answer (see above).  Sorry for the sloppiness and confusing method name.  This was working just fine for me.